# Dropdown tab animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am trying to replicate a web page(https://climate-science.com/contact/) using CSS, HTML and JS. I'm quite new to those 3 languages and I am having trouble trying to replicate the FAQ section. I'm having difficulty trying to make the animation, any help?

So far I have this in the HTML file(for 1 question):

```
            <div class="faq-container">
                <div class="element-tab-title">
                    <h4>When do we get more content?</h4>
                    <p>We put quality over quantity. That said, we have over 50 people working on content. More courses will be coming out over 2020 and new projects will be announced too! Thank you for being patient – we hope it will be worth it.</p>                    
                </div>
            </div>
```

The "faq-container" class contains the style for the grey box and the "element-tab-title" only contains the padding for the text inside. This is the result I have so far: [Photo of FAQ section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85MuB.png)

Any help on how to achieve the animation will be very appreciated.

Comment: What you're trying to make here is called an Accordion. jQuery UI has a widget built in that you can apply to markup with little coding. Alternatively, Google jQuery or Javascript accordion and you'll find plenty of examples.

Comment: Are there any advantages of using one of those rather than the other?

Comment: If you use a frontend framework such as bootstrap or jQuery UI, you do of course introduce the additional bloat into your website. Not a big deal, but every little counts. The upside is that they do a lot of stuff for you, and so save you development time. As accordions are so easy, I'd probably code it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually some simple Javascript would be used to toggle hide/show the 'body' content.

Your 'body' content is currently in your `<p>` tag, would normally be set to hidden with CSS by default, usually with`display:none`.

Then with Javascript, you would set an event listener to 'watch' for hover or click action from a user, when you would then change the CSS on the 'content' to be visible again with a different display type - usually `display:block`.

Here's a starter link on Javascript event listeners: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events

As user Geat suggested, you should have a look at Accordions in frontend frameworks. I would suggest looking at Bootstrap framework Accordions (such as https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/#accordion-example) where you can see some of the code and have a look at how it works.

Also, try to learn how to use your browser's developer tools/inspector to view the code as it's being rendered. This is especially helpful when you're trying to see how a live bit of code works as in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a really quick route, HTML5 supports accordions with no JS whatsoever. They're not animated, but they are easy to style and semantically easy to understand (so they're good for accessibility out of the box).

```html
<details>  
  <summary>Section 1</summary>  
  <h3>This is section 1</h3>  
</details>  
<details>  
  <summary>Section 2</summary>  
  <h3>This is section 2</h3>  
</details>  
<details>  
  <summary>Section 3</summary>  
  <h3>This is section 3</h3>  
</details>
```